# Spawn 2 enemies per second in GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm making a game in openGL and I want to spawn 2 enemies per second on the screen. The problem is, I'm calling the spawn function inside idle:

```
idle
{
    // ...
    world.spawnEnemy();
}
```

And then, in the spawnEnemy function:

```
void World::spawnEnemy()
{
    Enemy newEnemy, newEnemy2;

    float start;

    start = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

    // 1/2 a second passes
    while ( (glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - start) <= 500 )
    {
        ;
    }

    // create enemy
    newEnemy();
    pushToEnemyList(newEnemy);

    // another 1/2 second passes
    while ( (glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) - start) <= 1000 )
    {
        ;
    }

    // create enemy
    newEnemy2();
    pushToEnemyList(newEnemy2);
}
```

And this is not working, of course. Probably because idle is called everytime and I'm calling a function inside idle that waits for a certain amount of time to pass and then everything starts going wrong. The solution is to do the spawning in the idle function (without calling any function, doing all the logic inside idle), but I don't like this idea. I need to do more things in a certain number of time, for example, my enemies have guns and they will have to shoot n times every second. And if I do all of these directly inside of idle it will become a mess. So, basically, how do I make this work:

```
idle
{
    // ...
    world.spawnEnemy();
    world.enemyShoot();
    // another functionalities that depend on time
}
```

instead of this:

```
idle
{
   // ...
   // logic of spawnEnemy directly here in the idle function
   // logic of enemyShoot directly here in the idle function
   // logic of another functionalities that depend on time directly here in the idle function
}
```

Comment: Having a spin loop to grind gears and wait for a half second to pass is really not the best solution here. That'll cause 100% CPU usage and is the equivalent of stomping the gas pedal and the brake at the same time. Do you have an event loop that can fire off events on regular intervals? If not, you need one.

Comment: @tadman no, I don't. How can I do it? I really never did something like this before

Comment: Like a state machine it's actually pretty trivial to sketch in a basic event loop, but you'll probably want to look at how you can build out a more full-featured one. Windows itself is one example, everything important is facilitated through message passing to your main event handler. Most games have some kind of internal event loop, too, to help scheduling things, sometimes one tick per frame, sometimes independent of frame-rate. If you're writing code for games, one book that's invaluable is the [Game Engine Architecture](http://gameenginebook.com) one which covers all this and more.

Comment: `idle` seems to be your main loop. Just remember the time of the last enemy spawn. If this time is longer than half a second ago, spawn a new enemy and reset the spawn time.

Comment: You could write an event or hook class that is instanced at the top level of your code, the class could hold a list of function pointers and a way to register to that list. You can then call all the functions pointed to in that list each frame, and maybe fire some data like a time delta. It's also possible to write a macro that will register classes for you, so you can create new files and have them work with but completely independently of the rest of your game, you'll probably also want to look at data driven design.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few ways to do this here the most common:

1. **Measure elapsed time**

   Simply remember time of last spawn `t0` and on each (idle) iteration get current time `t`. If `t0+T<=t` then spawn new enemy ans set `t0=t`. The `T` is the period of spawning in the same units as the measured time. In your case `500ms`.

   As mentioned OnIdle Event will take `100%` of one **CPU** core for itself. To remedy this use `Sleep(x);`  where `x<<T` that will ease up on the **CPU** load (even `Sleep(1);` will be a big difference).

   To measure time use any **OS** routine you got available (with high enough accuracy) I am using `PerformanceCounter` on Windows but there are other alternatives like `RDTSC` etc ...
2. **Timers**

   Modern messaging based **OS** provides timer function which will fire your event periodically (usually with ~1ms accuracy). Just study your **API** to implement it. Then you just spawn your enemy inside timer event without any other logic or timing code ...

   In case you do not have any timers you can fake this by creating thread with code like this inside:

   ```
   for (;!spawn_exit;)
    {
    if (spawn_enabled) spawn(); 
    Sleep(T);
    }
   ```

   where `volatile bool spawn_enabled=true,spawn_exit=false;` are used to control the spawning and stop the thread (before App shutdown) But in this case be careful with multi threaded access in the `spawn()` function ...